# I am looking for the man in the middle software

Tags: penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I have got TamperData as a firefox extension. Is there a better software that is easy to use to intercept request calls and modify them..

Webscrab and Paros only half work and not good

Comment: What is your legitimate (read legal) use case?

Comment: penetration test on some site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with the free version of Burp Proxy

http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html

Just try it out :)

Comment: lol..it is not free and nothing appears when i browse

Comment: Ok I will directly point you to the download page if you can not find it :)
http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html

Comment: I will have to read all the tutorials to learn abou tit